# Does the "unnatural" blackjack after splitting push with the dealer?

Tags: blackjack

If I split aces, and get an "unnatural" (as they say in casinos), does the ante push if the dealer draws into a blackjack too, or does the dealer win?

I know, that it usually pays 1:1 at the casinos in this case. But what if it's a draw?

The word `unnatural' just confuses me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the house rules, which may be either determined by law (or subordinate regulation) or by the casino by publication.

The dealer will often make the rule explicit by stating that splits aces don't become blackjacks. In this case they cannot push on the dealer's blackjack, because they only have a 21 at best.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario will never happen when playing blackjack in a typical Vegas-style casino. [The hand ends immediately if the Dealer has (natural) Blackjack](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/blackjack/#:%7E:text=If%20the%20dealer%20has%20a%20natural,but%20no%20additional%20amount). So there will never be an opportunity for you to split your aces if the dealer has blackjack.

In [European-style casino rules](https://www.pagat.com/banking/blackjack.html#:%7E:text=In%20European%20style%20games,vary%20from%20casino%20to%20casino), the specific rules about how to handle the additional bets of double-downs and splits can vary, with some casinos returning the additional bets and others taking all the bets. But no matter how the additional bets are handled, all split hands (even if they are 2-card 21s) lose to a dealer's blackjack.

Comment: This is patently false in many casinos, wherein the dealer has only one card until all players have stood or bust and cannot know at all whether they will have a blackjack. The player can split aces, receive tens on both, before the dealer gets a blackjack and takes the player's money (variously, all or it or only the original bet).

Comment: @Nij sounds like a bad casino making up their own rules. Are those "typical"? References?

Comment: Sounds like a lawful requirement that the casinos cannot change... [New Zealand](https://www.dia.govt.nz/diawebsite.nsf/Files/Gambling-rules-August-2018/$file/Division-2-Blackjack.pdf) or [Australia Capital Territory](https://www.legislation.act.gov.au/DownloadFile/ni/2003-192/20030603-6107/PDF/2003-192.PDF&ved=2ahUKEwjI542o99_qAhXZzTgGHYrYAk0QFjAKegQIBhAH&usg=AOvVaw08oKB_GqsLJ6Z7ObbRnAgd&cshid=1595389076323) for example, as the initial deal.

Comment: @Nij huh, I was unaware that Blackjack variations were that different outside Las Vegas. I've updated my answer to clarify the Vegas-style rules.